# split String array to char array that is String[] to char[]

Tags: java, string

I have strings in array I want to split them into char array? is it possible??

I did this:

```
    // skipped the portion of code
    void somefunction(String[] gf){
      char[] charArrays = new char[500];
      charArrays = gf.toCharArray();   // not allowing to use toCharArray

    // skipped the portion of code
    }
```

Comment: When I see such code: `char[] charArrays = new char[500];charArrays = gf.toCharArray();` I know where the perfomance gain of new processors goes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int size = 0;
    for (String s : input) {
        size += s.length();
    }

    char[] output = new char[size];
    int start = 0;
    for (String s : input) {
        System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, output, start, s.length());
        start+=s.length();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`gf` is a `String[]`. You can apply the method in a single `String` instead:

```
for (String s : gf) {
    charArrays = s.toCharArray();
}
```

Here's a more concrete example of what you want/need to achieve (IMO):

```
void somefunction(String[] gf) {
    List<char[]> data = new ArrayList<char[]>();
    int wholeSize = 0;
    for (String s : gf) {
        char[] charArray = s.toCharArray();
        data.add(charArray);
        wholeSize += charArray.length;
    }
    char[] wholeStringIntoCharArray = new char[wholeSize];
    int i = 0;
    for (char[] charArray : data) {
        for (char c : charArray) {
            wholeStringIntoCharArray [i++] = c;
        }
    }
    //return wholeStringIntoCharArray;
}
```

Comment: where is function ending bro?

Comment: @user3508182 it would be better if you specify what's your real problem and how are you trying to solve it.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: so far I am unable to split the string[] to char[]. bcz after conducting ths I have to make a cross_over task

Comment: stack or stacktrace? I know abt stack which follows first-in-lastout but I don't know stacktrace

Comment: @user3508182 stacktrace. It is the error message being printed where shows the exception (the problem), where it is (name of method, location in file) and the places where this error impacted. It usually starts with `java.lang.NullPointerException at ...`.

Comment: @user3508182 the picture doesn't contain the stactrace, so I'm unable to spot any error.

Comment: i have spend gr8 hrs in solving that issue

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version:

```
    String[] stringArray = new String[]{"abc", "qwe", "www"};
    List<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (String string : stringArray) {
        for (char ch : string.toCharArray()) {
            charList.add(ch);
        }
    }
    Character[] finalArray = charList.toArray(new Character[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this:
*I have strings in array I want to split them into char array? is it possible??*

YES it is possible.
You must **join first** and **then split** in an array of characters. try the following:

```
String result = ("" + Arrays.asList(gf)).replaceAll("(^.|.$)", "").replace(", ", "" );

char[] charArrays = result.toCharArray();
```